# homebrew mysql installation error

Tags: mysql, command-line, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to install MySQL via homebrew and I keep getting an error:

```
brew install mysql
==> Installing mysql dependency: openssl
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/openssl-1.0

curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
Error: Failed to download resource "openssl"
Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/openssl-1.0.1h.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: /usr/local/opt/makedepend not present or broken
Please reinstall makedepend. Sorry :(
```

What might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got same error when I tried to install python3

Answer (score 19):

try to do :

```
brew install makedepend
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:
`brew update`

I helped me with SSL dependency.